# Записать список в файл с индексами

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, список

Есть такой список

```
HTML: [{'title': 'Расписание занятий 2-4 курсов с 13.09.21 (2 поток)', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru//upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_2-4_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_13.09.21_%282_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%29.xls'}, {'title': 'Замена на 14 сентября 2021 г.', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru/https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://academicol.ru/upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/Замена_на_14_сентября_2021_г..docx'}, {'title': 'Расписание занятий 1-2 курсов с 13.09.21 (1 поток)', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru//upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_1-2_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_13.09.21_%281_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%29.xls'}, {'title': 'Замена на 13 сентября 2021 г.', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru/https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://academicol.ru/upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/Замена_на_13_сентября_2021_г..docx'}, {'title': 'Замена на 15 сентября 2021 г.', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru/https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://academicol.ru/upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/Замена_на_15_сентября_2021_г..docx'}, {'title': 'Расписание занятий для 1 курсов с 13.09.21', 'link': 'https://academicol.ru//upload/price/postoynnoe_spo/para/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_1_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_13.09.21.xls'}]
```

Я его записал в файл:

```
with open('done_sc.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as filehandle:  
     for listitem in self.done_sc:
         filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Потом в другом скрипте считал:

```
done_sc = [] 
with open('done_sc.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as filehandle:
     for line in filehandle:
         # удалим заключительный символ перехода строки
         currentPlace = line[:-1]

         # добавим элемент в конец списка
         done_sc.append(currentPlace)
```

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь обратиться к элементам **title** или **link**, происходит ошибка

```
print('LINK', [[d['link']] for d in done_sc])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь работать со списком как со словарём.
Вам следует пересмотреть способ хранения данных. Для структур в виде словаря лучше подходит формат json. Вы сможете сохранять и доставать ваши списки и словари с помощью встроенной библиотеки json с большей лёгкостью.